# How can I refer from another components style which is from material ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have
`UserListPage`
components and it's styled like this.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      width: "100%",
      height: "97vh",
      paddingTop: "5vh",
      paddingBottom: "5vh",
    },
  })
);
```

When I have another components let's say `WorkingUserListPage`, How can I refer `UserListPage` root?

I don't want to write the style again in `WorkingUserListPage`.

Comment: modulize the useStyles in a different file and import it many times…

Comment: Thank you! How can I call it? I don't know how to write. `<Components className={useStyles.classes.root} />` like this?

Comment: you should look at mui’s docs to see how to implement the classes functionality with usestyles hook

Comment: Could you give the link?

Comment: google is also very helpful. sadly my current internet is blocked and i cant.. but i do not suggest you to rely on platforms like this in such minor issues